# XPath - select nodes for which all child nodes of one name have a particular child node themselves

Tags: xml, xpath

To explain the slightly verbose title, I have a document satisfying the following DTD

```
<!ELEMENT books (book)+>
<!ELEMENT book (author*, title, isbn?)>
<!ELEMENT author (first-name?, last-name)>
```

and I am looking for an XPath expression selecting all books for which each author child of that book has a first-name child.

I have absolutely no idea how to achieve this 'for all'-type query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following XPath expression should work:

```
//book[author and not(author[not(first-name)])]
```

It says: find a book anywhere that has an author and doesn't have an autor that has no first name.

Comment: +1 - XPath (1.0) often requires these "double negative" constructs for this sort of thing.  Many of the operators are implicitly existentially quantified, so to do "for all X: Y" you have to do "not(for some X: not(Y))"

Comment: Just been getting my head around SQL's double not exists, so this seems to tie in quite nicely, very neat